# Ransacker : Unsupported argument type: String. Construct an Arel node instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am trying to contact two fields and then search using ransack. I have a User model and two fields: first_name and last_name and I want to search users using full name. Here is what I am using :

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
      parent.table[:first_name], ' '
    ),
    parent.table[:last_name]
  )
end
```

but I am getting this error: **Unsupported argument type: String. Construct an Arel node instead.** after passing the fullname into search field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replace my code with following:

```
ransacker :full_name, formatter: proc { |v| v.mb_chars.downcase.to_s } do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('LOWER',
   [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws',
    [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' '), parent.table[:first_name], 
  parent.table[:last_name]])])
end
```

This solved the issue.